# How can i enable disable an action button based on a string in a line in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have created an application which enables the user to run a query and fetch the results from rodbc. By default the query which is getting generated in the TextAreaInput is select * from $tableName. I have an action button 'Go' next to that Input box and when i press go the query gets executed and the result is fetched in the body.
Now, I want the 'Go' button to be enabled only when the select query has 'when' clause in it. In short the user should be able to execute only when they have included a where clause in the query. I tied str_detect and grpl but they don't seem to be working. Amy help is much appriciated.

Regards

```
body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    width=12,
    column(
      width=11,
      textAreaInput2( inputId = "query",label = "Enter Query", width = "100%")
    ),
    column(
      width = 1,
      actionButton(inputId = "runQuery", label = "Go",style="width:70px",class="btn-lg"),
      class="align-middle",style = "height:100px;text-align:center;margin-top:25px;"
    ),style = "height:100px"
  ),
  dataTableOutput('table'),
  fluidRow(width = 12, column(
    width=10)
)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "green", header,sidebar, body)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  resultTable <-  data.frame()
  observeEvent(input$tableName, {
    nQuery = paste("SELECT * FROM ",input$tableName,sep = "" )
    updateTextAreaInput(session, "query", value = nQuery)
  })
  observeEvent(input$runQuery, {
    resultTable <<- sqlQuery (channel = conn, query = input$query)
    output$table <- renderDataTable(resultTable)}
  )
```

Comment: The ‘shinyjs’ package may help: https://deanattali.com/shinyjs/

Comment: I am unable to derive the logic for this. I need to disable the 'Go' button if when is not there in the sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shinyjs` can enable/disable buttons for us. `grepl` can tell us if a string contains another string. The below minimal example shows this in action:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(

    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

    textAreaInput("txt_query", label = "Enter Query", width = "100%"),

    actionButton("btn_run", label = "Run Query")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    #Observe the query text box (runs when the query text box changes)
    observeEvent(input$txt_query, {

        #Check if the query contains the word 'when'
        if (grepl("when", input$txt_query) == TRUE) {

            #Enable the run button
            shinyjs::enable("btn_run")

        } else {

            #Disable the run button
            shinyjs::disable("btn_run")

        }

    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```